# Posting json data to WebAPI method in angularjs

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

```
$scope.items = {2: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 9: true, 10: true, 11: true };
```

How do I post the above json data to the following WebAPI method using angularjs's $http?

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("moveemployees")]
public HttpResponseMessage MoveEmployees(Dictionary<decimal, bool> employeeList)     
    {
         // employeeList doesn't contain any items after the post
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

I tried :

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: $scope.appPath + 'Employee/moveemployees',
        data: { employeeList : $scope.items },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
           }
        }).success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.infos.push('Employees Moved Successfully');
            $scope.errors = [];
        }).error(function (data, status) {                
     });
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tested this, works fine:

```
[Route("moveemployees")]
public void Post(Dictionary<decimal, bool> employeeList)
{

}
```

and:

```
$scope.items = { 2: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 9: true, 10: true, 11: true };
var config = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "moveemployees",
    data: $scope.items
};
$http(config);
```

What error response are you getting? Might be something like not including an authorization header in your request and getting a 401 due to the Authorize attribute on you Api endpoint?

Comment: I changed `data: { employeeList : $scope.items }` to `data: $scope.items` and it worked. Weird!

Comment: @amarduplantier It's not weird, when posting data you don't use named parameters, you use named parameters when you use `params` to pass in parameters to your api, much like you would during get requests.

Comment: I didn't know, ty. :)